# How to compare time in Linq?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

net application. I have one table which stores datetime in one column. I am trying to get the count of entries made to this column in last one hour. I tried as below.

```
var count = context.Db2FailureEvents
    .Where(x => x.Timestamp >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60))
    .Count();
```

This will not return entries made in last one hour. This will return entries made in last one day. Below is one sample date in table 2019-03-25 10:12:25. May I know why I am not getting records made in last one hour? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Whats the datatype of `Timestamp`?

Comment: Hi, It is timestamp

Comment: Alright, and is the underlying storage a SQL Server or are we talking about something different (MySQL/Oracle)? SQL Server's timestamp doesn't represent a date and/or time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am using sql.

Comment: Rowversion is incrementing number. How can I get entries made in last one hour?

Comment: No, you'll have to add a column representing that date/time. There's no information in a `timestamp` when it was created. The name of the datatype is rather confusing in that regard.

Comment: For Entity Framework take a look at [DbFunctions.DiffMinutes Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffminutes?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbFunctions_DiffMinutes_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__System_Nullable_System_DateTime__)

Comment: Hi So i should change from timestamp to rowversion? After that how can i find last one hour entries?

Comment: can you try hours `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)`

Comment: @Niranjan: No, timestamp is rowversion. You have to change to DateTime or DateTime2

Comment: actually it was already datetime and field was  [Column("Timestamp")]
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; } by mistek i said timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked for me.

I also tried `"(x => x.Timestamp.**Value** >="` since you mentioned that you used `DateTime?`, which also works for me.